# Android Location

Tags: android, gps, location

When I use getLastKnownLocation() function it turns on the GPS why?

if any one knows it. I need to know this flow.

Regards
Shah Nawaz Asif

Answer (score 0):

Is this the emulator ? or a real device ?

According to the [Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#getLastKnownLocation%28java.lang.String%29)

> If the provider is currently disabled, **null** is returned.

Therefore you can't receive the location if it's disabled anyway.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using emulator, there is tool in android SDK called "ddms" 
run it and go to tab named "Emulator Control", From this option you can send GPS location to your android emulator, than your code should work fine.

If you are on real device, check the network provider you are giving to this function is actually enabled, GPS, or NETWORK.